# How to create a variable in constructor and pass it to super()

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to write a class, `FadePainter`, which extends [`CustomPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) with a custom GLSL shader. In order to use the shader, I first need to load it, which is (indirectly) an `async` operation. I want to do this within my `FadePainter` class as I don't want to have to pass this as an argument. I can easily trigger the load function from my constructor, however I need some way of triggering a repaint once it's finished loading. This can be done with the optional `repaint` `Listenable` parameter for `CustomPainter`.

However, I can't find any way of passing a `Listenable` (such as `ChangeNotifier`) to the `super` constructor while storing it within my `FadePainter` class, so I can actually trigger it. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```dart
class FadePainter extends CustomPainter {
  FadePainter() {
    final repaint = ChangeNotifier();
    loadShader(repaint); // Pass ChangeNotifier to loadShader, which can then use it to trigger repaint
    super(repaint: repaint);
  }
}
```

or even:

```dart
class FadePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ChangeNotifier repaint = ChangeNotifier();

  FadePainter() : super(repaint: repaint);
}
```

but neither of these are valid syntax. The first one complains that `super()` doesn't evaluate to a function (because the `super` constructor doesn't work like this in Dart); and the second says that the instance member can't be accessed in the constructor.

There are two obvious alternatives, neither of which I like:

- I can pass a `ChangeNotifier` to `FadePainter` constructor. However, this only needs to be used internally in this one very specific situation. It doesn't make sense to have it passed in as a parameter.
- I can implement `CustomPainter` and extend `ChangeNotifier`, but this adds a lot of (seemingly) unnecessary boilerplate.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the default constructor [redirect](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#redirecting-constructors) to a private, intermediate constructor so that the `ChangeNotifier` is bound to a constructor parameter:

```dart
class FadePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ChangeNotifier repaint;

  FadePainter() : this._(ChangeNotifier());

  FadePainter._(this.repaint)
    : super(repaint: repaint);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a really weird way of doing it, but that must be the only way.